# How can I append multiple extensions to a string with sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I want to create a script that will let me download images from entire subreddits at once, but I'm currently stuck on just getting the links right (one problem at a time! ^^). Anyway, since I can't think of a way to determine what format the image in the link will be, I was hoping *sed* could be used to specify multiple extensions during replacement (e.g. (jpg|png|gif)), but this does not seem to work.

```
grep -E "href=\"/r/bacon/*" bacon.htm | sed "s .*/r/bacon/\(.*\)\".* http://i.imgur.com/\1.\(\jpg\|\png\|\gif\) "
```

expected:

```
http://i.imgur.com/foo.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/foo.png
http://i.imgur.com/foo.gif
```

got:

```
http://i.imgur.com/foo.(jpg|png|gif)
```

Google also does not seem to have an answer to this, admittedly, weird problem or at least I am having trouble coming up with meaningful ways to describe it.

Any ideas or should I try this from a different angle?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You may want to show a more step-wise statement of the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, but like I said, the problem is weird and difficult to describe (at least to me).
My question is: How can one edit a string in such a way (using sed) that the output produces multiple variations of that string?
I think TimP provided a good solution to this question, but I do find drewbenn's solution to the overall problem more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question right your `grep` is going to produce a bunch of strings like this:

```
href="http://reddit.com/r/bacon/foo"
```

And you want to turn each of them into something like:

```
http://i.imgur.com/foo.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/foo.png
http://i.imgur.com/foo.gif
```

It's not particularly graceful, but you could just do:

```
sed "s .*/r/bacon/\(.*\)\".* http://i.imgur.com/\1.jpg\nhttp://i.imgur.com/\1.png\nhttp://i.imgur.com/\1.gif "
```

Example:

```
timp@helez:~/tmp$ cat bacon.lines 
href="http://reddit.com/r/bacon/foo"
href="http://reddit.com/r/bacon/bar"
timp@helez:~/tmp$ cat bacon.lines | sed "s .*/r/bacon/\(.*\)\".* http://i.imgur.com/\1.jpg\nhttp://i.imgur.com/\1.png\nhttp://i.imgur.com/\1.gif "
http://i.imgur.com/foo.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/foo.png
http://i.imgur.com/foo.gif
http://i.imgur.com/bar.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/bar.png
http://i.imgur.com/bar.gif
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside a loop, instead

```
extension_list="jpg png gif" #easy to add other extensions later, like JPG
: # ... other stuff in the script
for extension in $extension_list
do
    sed "s/foo\(bar\)baz/\1.$extension/"
    # if you get the file you want, you can use 'break' to exit the loop early
done
```

This is out of scope of your actual question, but instead of combining grep and sed you can (if you want) use just sed to print matching lines, like:

```
sed -n "s+.*/r/bacon/\(.*\)\".*+http://i.imgur.com/\1.$extension+p" bacon.htm
```

Comment: Cool solution, much more elegant than my approach. Just out of curiosity, how can I use 'break' to exit the loop early? Could you provide a quick example of this?